# How to convert Date as number to Date with "-"

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I am fetching an API response where I got Date like this

> 20180224 (it is of type number)

I need to convert it in String date format like

> '2018-02-24'

I am trying like

```
a = 20180224;
a[5] = '-';
```

but it does not work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```
 (\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})
    |       |      |
   YYYY    MM     DD 
  ( G1 ) ( G2 ) ( G2 )
```

```js
let str = `20180224`

let op = str.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, `$1-$2-$3`)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function and some RegExp:

```js
var dateAsNumber = 20180224;
var dateAsString = dateAsNumber.toString().replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3");
console.log(dateAsString);
```